# Antlr Extraneous Input

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4

I have a grammar file BoardFile.g4 that has (relevant parts only):

```
grammar Board;

//Tokens
GADGET : 'squareBumper' | 'circleBumper' | 'triangleBumper' | 'leftFlipper' | 'rightFlipper' | 'absorber' | 'portal' ;
NAME : [A-Za-z_][A-Za-z_0-9]* ;
INT : [0-9]+ ;
FLOAT : '-'?[0-9]+('.'[0-9]+)? ;
COMMENT : '#' ~( '\r' | '\n' )*;
WHITESPACE : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;
KEY : [a-z] | [0-9] | 'shift' | 'ctrl' | 'alt' | 'meta' | 'space' | 'left' | 'right' | 'up' | 'down' | 'minus' | 'equals' | 'backspace' | 'openbracket' | 'closebracket' | 'backslash' | 'semicolon' | 'quote' | 'enter' | 'comma' | 'period' | 'slash' ;
KEYPRESS : 'keyup' | 'keydown' ;

//Rules
file : define+ EOF ;
define : board | ball | gadget | fire | COMMENT | key ;
board : 'board' 'name' '=' name ('gravity' '=' gravity)? ('friction1' '=' friction1)? ('friction2' '=' friction2)? ;
ball : 'ball' 'name' '=' name 'x' '=' xfloat 'y' '=' yfloat 'xVelocity' '=' xvel 'yVelocity' '=' yvel ;
gadget : gadgettype 'name' '=' name 'x' '=' xint 'y' '=' yint ('width' '=' width 'height' '=' height)? ('orientation' '=' orientation)? ('otherBoard' '=' name 'otherPortal' '=' name)? ;
fire : 'fire' 'trigger' '=' trigger 'action' '=' action ;
key : keytype 'key' '=' KEY 'action' '=' name ;

name : NAME ;
gadgettype : GADGET ;
keytype : KEYPRESS ;
gravity : FLOAT ;
friction1 : FLOAT ;
friction2 : FLOAT ;
trigger : NAME ;
action : NAME ;
yfloat : FLOAT ;
xfloat : FLOAT ;
yint : INT ;
xint : INT ;
xvel : FLOAT ;
yvel : FLOAT ;
orientation : INT ;
width : INT ;
height : INT ;
```

This generates the lexer and parser fine. However, when I use it against  the following file, it gives the following error:

```
line 12:0 extraneous input 'keyup' expecting {<EOF>, KEYPRESS}
```

**File to Parse:**

board name=keysBoard gravity=5.0 friction1=0.0 friction2=0.0

```
# define a ball
ball name=Ball x=0.5 y=0.5 xVelocity=2.5 yVelocity=2.5

# add some flippers
leftFlipper name=FlipL1 x=16 y=2 orientation=0
leftFlipper name=FlipL2 x=16 y=9 orientation=0

# add keys. lots of keys.
keyup key=space action=apple
keydown key=a action=ball
keyup key=backslash action=cat
keydown key=period action=dog
```

I went through other questions about this error in SO but none helped me. I cannot figure out what's going wrong. Why am I getting this error?

Comment: What is your question? What do you *expect* your code to do?

Comment: I want to parse the file correctly. Why am I getting the error? Sorry for not making it clear- I've updated the question.

Comment: how are you dealing with newlines?

Comment: I ignore all newLines. I have `WHITESPACE : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;` in the grammar.

Comment: What does "parse the file correctly" mean?

Comment: Parse the file. Right now I get the above error and so, the "keys" just don't get parsed.

Comment: What are the details of the parser rule 'name'? I tried your grammar and hard-coded 'apple' for 'name'. The parser could parse your first input line "keyup key=space action=apple". Probably, you need to provide a scaled down but fully working grammar and an input that shows the error.

Comment: I've edited the question to include the entire grammar and the file I'm trying to parse.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The string `"keyup"` is being tokenized as a `NAME` token: that is the problem.

You must realize that the lexer operates independently from the parser. If the parser is trying to match a `KEYPRESS` token, the lexer does not "listen" to it, but just constructs a token following the rules:

1. match the rule that consumes the most characters
2. if there are more rules that match the same amount of characters, choose the one that is defined first

Taking these rules into account, and the order of your rules:

```
NAME : [A-Za-z_][A-Za-z_0-9]* ;

INT : [0-9]+ ;

KEY : [a-z] | [0-9] | 'shift' | 'ctrl' | 'alt' | 'meta' | 'space' | 'left' | 'right' | 'up' | 'down' | 'minus' | 'equals' | 'backspace' | 'openbracket' | 'closebracket' | 'backslash' | 'semicolon' | 'quote' | 'enter' | 'comma' | 'period' | 'slash' ;

KEYPRESS : 'keyup' | 'keydown' ;
```

a `NAME` token will be created before most of the `KEY` alternatives, and all of the `KEYPRESS` alternatives will be created.

And since an `INT` matches one or more digits and is defined before `KEY` which also has a single digit alternative, it is clear that the lexer will never produce a `KEY` or `KEYPRESS` token.

If you move the `NAME` and `INT` rule below the `KEY` and `KEYPRESS` rules, then most of the tokens will be constructed as you expect, is my guess.

### EDIT

A possible solution would look like:

```
KEY : [a-z] | 'shift' | 'ctrl' | 'alt' | 'meta' | 'space' | 'left' | 'right' | 'up' | 'down' | 'minus' | 'equals' | 'backspace' | 'openbracket' | 'closebracket' | 'backslash' | 'semicolon' | 'quote' | 'enter' | 'comma' | 'period' | 'slash' ;

KEYPRESS : 'keyup' | 'keydown' ;

NAME : [A-Za-z_][A-Za-z_0-9]* ;

SINGLE_DIGIT : [0-9] ;

INT : [0-9]+ ;
```

I.e. I removed the `[0-9]` alternative from `KEY` and introduced a `SINGLE_DIGIT` rule (which is placed *before* the `INT` rule!).

Now create some extra parser rules:

```
integer : INT | SINGLE_DIGIT ;

key : KEY | SINGLE_DIGIT ;
```

and change all occurrences of `INT` inside parser rules to `integer` (don't call your rule `int`: it is a reserved word) and change all `KEY` to `key`.

And you might also want to do something similar to `NAME` and the `[a-z]` alternative in `KEY` (i.e. a single lowercase char would now never be tokenized as a `NAME`, always as a `KEY`).

Comment: Thank you very much! That worked! However, now that I have KEY before NAME and INT, things like `leftFlipper name=a x=16 y=2 orientation=0` gives an error because now, name matches KEY before it matches NAME.

Comment: @AashishTripathee, indeed, a single digit would now *not* be matched as an `INT` but as a `KEY`.

Comment: You saved my bacon. Thanks!